# In focframework how can I make a button that prints several Jasper reports concatenated together in one print

Tags: java, vaadin

I am using [focframework](https://www.focframework.com/) to build my web application. I already have a few independent Jasper reports developed and working properly in focframework independently. Now I want to have a button that allows to print them all together in one shot, by concatenating them in the same PDF file.

Obviously I would use the [Vaadin](https://vaadin.com/) BrowserWindowOpener as follows. But then I should prepare a resource object.

```
StreamResource resource = ???;
BrowserWindowOpener browserWindowOpener = new BrowserWindowOpener(resource);
browserWindowOpener.extend(button);
```

Any Idea how to place the concatenation of Jasper reports in the StreamResource object?

I know there are some answers out there that explain how to do it in general but since I am using [focframework](https://www.focframework.com/) I wanted a more targeted answer allowing me to use existing foc development if any.

Answer (score 2):

As you mentioned in your question, using BrowserWindowOpener looks like the right way.

```
StreamResource resource = ???;
BrowserWindowOpener browserWindowOpener = new BrowserWindowOpener(resource);
browserWindowOpener.extend(button);
```

To get a "StreamResource resource" we can do the following:

```
StreamResource resource = new StreamResource(streamSource, "printnig_"+System.currentTimeMillis()+".pdf");
resource.setMIMEType("application/pdf");
```

Now we need a streamSource of type com.vaadin.server.StreamSource. To get that we have a dedicated class that concatenates reports, I hope this answers your needs:

```
FStreamSource_Report<MyUserDataClass> streamSource = new FStreamSource_Report<MyUserDataClass>(myUserDataClassInstance) {
protected void init(int reportIndex){
    //init to print the report at reportIndex.
}

protected void shut(int reportIndex){
    //dispose the necessary data for reportIndex
}

protected boolean next(int reportIndex){
    //Return true if you have a report to print at reportIndex
}

protected String getReportFileName(int reportIndex){
    //Return the report filename at reportIndex
}

protected JRFocObjectParameters getParams(int reportIndex){
    //Return the JRFocObjectParameters needed for reportIndex
}

protected JRFocListDataSource getDataSource(int reportIndex){
    //Return the Jasper/foc Data source for the Jasper details section at reportIndex
}
```

You will obviously have to implement the different methods listed above. These method calls will tell FStreamSource_Report how many underlying reports it has and they will be called each time to prepare the data for these reports.

MyUserDataClass: is a class of your choice that will be accessible to you inside the different method implementation using the getUserData();

**Here's an example:**
    FStreamSource_Report streamSource = new FStreamSource_Report(prodProgram) {

```
    private PrintingAction printingAction = null;

    @Override
    protected void init(int reportIndex) {
        if(reportIndex == 0){//Raw Material printout 
            ProductionProgram productionProgram = getUserData();
            printingAction = RawMaterialReportDesc.getInstance().newPrintingAction();
            printingAction.setObjectToPrint(productionProgram);
            printingAction.initLauncher();

        }else if(reportIndex == 1){//Production Steps
            ProductionProgram productionProgram = getUserData();
            printingAction = ProductionStepsReportDesc.getInstance().newPrintingAction();
            printingAction.setObjectToPrint(productionProgram);
            printingAction.initLauncher();

        }else if(reportIndex == 2){//Production Steps                   
            ProductionProgram productionProgram = getUserData();
            printingAction = FinishedProductsReportDesc.getInstance().newPrintingAction();
            printingAction.setObjectToPrint(productionProgram);
            printingAction.initLauncher();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void shut(int reportIndex) {
        if(printingAction != null){
            printingAction.dispose();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected String getReportFileName(int reportIndex) {
        String fileName = null;
        PrnContext prnContext = ReportFactory.getInstance().findContext("PRODUCTION_CONTEXT");
        if (prnContext != null) {
            PrnLayout prnLayout = null;
            if(reportIndex == 0) {
                prnLayout = prnContext.getLayoutByName("RAW_MATERIAL");
            }else if(reportIndex == 1) {
                prnLayout = prnContext.getLayoutByName("STEPS");
            }else if(reportIndex == 2) {
                prnLayout = prnContext.getLayoutByName("FINISHED_PRODUCTS");
            }
            if (prnLayout != null) {
                fileName = printingAction != null ? 
                printingAction.getLauncher().getReportFileName(prnLayout) : null;   
            }
        }
        return fileName;
    }

    @Override
    protected JRFocObjectParameters getParams(int reportIndex) {
        JRFocObjectParameters params = null;
        if(reportIndex == 0 || reportIndex == 1 || reportIndex == 2){
            //I am using the same header FocObject for all 3 reports
            ProductionProgram productionProgram = getUserData();
            params = new JRFocObjectParameters(productionProgram);  
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected JRFocListDataSource getDataSource(int reportIndex) {
        JRFocListDataSource source = null;
        if(reportIndex == 0){//Raw material
            ProductionProgram productionProgram = getUserData();
            source = new JRFocListDataSource(productionProgram.getRawMaterialFocList());
        }else if(reportIndex == 1){//Production Steps
            ProductionProgram productionProgram = getUserData();
            source = new JRFocListDataSource(productionProgram.getProductionStepsFocList());
        }else if(reportIndex == 2){//Production Steps
            ProductionProgram productionProgram = getUserData();
            source = new JRFocListDataSource(productionProgram.getFinishedGoodsFocList());                  
        }

        return source;
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean next(int reportIndex) {
        return reportIndex <= 2;//Because we have 3 printouts 1,2,3
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

What you cannot do is just concatenate all the bytes of the different files one after another.

Jasper Reports has options to nest different Reports inside one another. Maybe just creating a big Report with your multiple Reports inside will work.

This would allow you to control page breaks, style etc. inside of Jasper

Comment: Maybe you are referring to Jasper sub reports. This would be a solution obviously. Yet I have also posted another answer using focframework objects; Internally what foc does is calling the Jasper reports one after the other then concatenate the PDF pages and generate a single bytes array. Each report will start at a new page.